# Evaluate $∫_0^{π/2} (3\sin^2 x + 8\cos^2 x) \, dx$

Tags: calculus

How do I do this question using this equation that I have already proven:

$$
∫_{0}^{π/2}  f(\sin x)\,dx = ∫_{0}^{π/2} f(\cos x)\,dx
$$
What went through my mind was that I let $f(x) = x^2$ so $f(\sin x)$ and $f(\cos x)$ would fit into the equation but I couldn't seem to get the answer which I think is $11π/4$.

Answer (score 0):

By the formula you mention,
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}(3\sin^2x+8\cos^2x)\,dx=
\int_0^{\pi/2}(3\cos^2x+8\sin^2x)\,dx
$$
and therefore, summing up,
$$
2I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}11\,dx=\frac{11}{2}\pi
$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin{x})dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos{x})dx$$

From which you can deduce,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2{x}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2{x}dx$$

You can break the given integral as,

$$I=3\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2{x}dx+8\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2{x}dx$$

Using the above equation, you can write this as,

$$I=3\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2{x}dx+8\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2{x}dx$$

Adding them both,

You get

$$2I=3\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}dx+8\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}dx=11\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}dx$$

$$2I=\frac{11\pi}{2}$$

$$I=\frac{11\pi}{4}$$